# List all the numbers in various ranges (1 - 6; 1, 2, 5 & 23; etc)

Tags: regex, excel, numbers, range, vba

I am working on a project where I have a column of Ward Group data, and the data is formatted as Municipality Name - Type (City, Town, Village) Wards. So for example:

```
ADAMS - T 1 & 2  
Cumberland V 1 - 5  
Marshfield - C 1 - 20, 23 - 25 & 27  
....  
etc.
```

To link this information to a government-provided ward shapefile, I need to have one line per Ward. So for example, I need to turn the above information into:

```
ADAMS - T 1  
ADAMS - T 2  
Cumberland V 1  
Cumberland V 2  
Cumberland V 3  
Cumberland V 4  
Cumberland V 5  
Marshfield - C 1  
....  
Marshfield - C 20  
Marshfield - C 23  

Marshfield - C 24  
Marshfield - C 25  
Marshfield - C 27
```

Also, each Ward Group line has several columns of election data, that I want copied into each new row. So for example:

```
Ward Group             Total Votes    
ADAMS - T 1 & 2          300
```

needs to become:

```
Ward Group       Total Votes     
ADAMS - T 1        300  
ADAMS - T 2        300
```

Is there a way to do this in Excel that isn't by hand, either formula or VBA?

Answer (score 1):

Although not tagged as such, I suspect you are going to require code for this, so means your question "must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results." or could be deem off topic. So perhaps a start with formulae (assuming each 'row' is a single cell):

1. maybe regex to make the Municipality Name - Type linking more consistent (say look for letter space letter space and replace with letter space hyphen space letter space - so `Cumberland V 1 - 5` ends up in a similar format to the others, ie `Cumberland - V 1 - 5`.)
2. then use `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",",",1)` to replace the hyphens before the Type with commas (can reply on hyphens because used for range indication also).
3. Then "fix" the results (Paste Special Values to replace the formulae).
4. Then parse out the results (Text to Columns) with "," and "&" as the delimiters (only).
5. Insert three new columns immediately to the right of the left of these columns and parse the (existing) left column with Space and hyphen as the delimiters.

Applied to your example, at this point the results should look so:

[image: SO18645869 example]

Columns C & D are the lower and upper bounds of ranges - but I'm afraid E3 alone represents a range (though this could be split out with Text To Columns again - a point to watch out for may be confusing 27-29 with 27 & 29.

There is more could be done with formulae but I think VBA is a better bet - unless perhaps this is definitely a 'once off' requirement. For example, the votes, if in a different cell, could be attached after the pages (?) have been split out, via say a lookup function.